# Appcelerator Error when building a new project for iOS

Tags: appcelerator

I just updated appcelerator after not working with it for a few months. I created a new project and attempted to build it for iPad Air (v10.2) It completely fails to build with the following errors:

```
2017-03-02T16:18:01.679Z | DEBUG  | Titanium Downloads Last Checked: 1488468509275
2017-03-02T16:18:03.713Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
Rebuild failed:
2017-03-02T16:18:03.714Z | ERROR  | Rebuild failed:

node-pre-gyp http GET https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v0.11.2/node_ios_device-v0.11.2-node-v51-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v0.11.2/node_ios_device-v0.11.2-node-v51-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v0.11.2/node_ios_device-v0.11.2-node-v51-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-ios-device@0.11.2 and node@7.4.0 (node-v51 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http Pre-built binary not available for your system, looked for https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v0.11.2/node_ios_device-v0.11.2-node-v51-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
```

My node version is 7.4.0

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Ok answering my own question here again.

Not sure why I am getting the 404 trying to get the module, but I resolved this by changing directory to 
~/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.GA/node_modules

then running:
npm install node-ios-device

not sure if this will help anyone else out but it got me over the hump.

Comment: Worked for me too :) Except that I had to move to `~/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.GA/` (without the node_modules) to install the npm package. Thanks!